# AVAudioPlayer along with seek bar and play pause button

Tags: xcode, avaudioplayer

I want to design audio player view to play my audio file.

I am bit confused about `AVAudioPlayer` working.
When I use `AVAudioPlayer`, it plays my audio file very well.

But I also want PLAY/PAUSE button and seek bar which will show the progress bar.

My question is that,
is there any inbuilt library or code that I can directly inherit and apply...?
or do I need to create those buttons and seek bar programatically and add them on view while playing the file...?

Thanks in advance.
I tried to search but all shows `AVAudioPlayer` working,
Nothing found four PLAY/PAUSE buttons additions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently making a music player, and I made my own control view using UIButtons for Play, Pause, Next, Previous, and a UISlider for seeking. There is no built in AvAudioPlayer controls that I know of for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I did the same